# Exibir dados do ajax, retornados pelo controller na view

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, mvc

Olá, estou com dificuldade em exibir os dados retornados pelo controller via chamada ajax

meu js é esse:

```
var requestList =  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data:null,
    url:"index.php/Pages/loadComentarios"
}); 

requestList.done(function(e) {
    var table;


    table = e;
    for (var key in e) {
        console.log({
        key: key,
        value: e[key]
    });    
}

    $('#comentario').html(table);


});
```

Esse é o controller (ignorem a consulta ao bd no controller, vou passar para o model quando eu conseguir exibir os dados na view)

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view("template/header");
        $this->load->view("template/content");
        $this->load->view("template/footer");
    }

    public function loadComentarios(){
        $data = $this->db->get("comentario")->result_array(); //colocar na model depois
        $dados = array('comentarios' => $data);
        //print_r($dados) ;
        echo json_encode($dados);

    }



}
```

essa é a minha view

```
<div id="comentario">
        <p><b>Autor:</b> José</p>
        <p><b>Data:</b> 09/04/2018 </p>
        <p><b>Comentário:</b> Lorem Ipsum dolor at</p>
    </div>
```

Essa é a forma com que os dados me são retornados

```
{"comentarios":[{"id":"1","id_autor":"1","comentario":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor at Pae Dum","criacao":"2018-04-17"},{"id":"3","id_autor":"1","comentario":"Teste de Coment\u00e1rio","criacao":"2018-04-01"},{"id":"4","id_autor":"2","comentario":"Teste novo de Coment\u00e1rio sem Autor","criacao":"2018-04-09"},{"id":"5","id_autor":"2","comentario":"ao comentario ehnois","criacao":"2018-04-11"}]}
```

Já tentei retornar os dados em json e em array normal, mas não consigo acessar os indices para exibir como eu quero, estou usando o codeigniter, estou aprendendo mvc agora

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: Na sua requisição ajax, o seu "data" está null...

Já agora, apenas um conselho... não sei se está aprendendo CI por iniciativa própria ou se por um motivo especifico.. mas pessoalmente aconselho a dar uma chance a Laravel. :)

Comment: É que não quero enviar nenhum dado p/ controller, eu to usando só pra receber os dados do bd que ele traz de volta, se eu colocar o E que retorna do controller na div de comentarios, ele aparece os dados todos em json ou array normal, mas eu não consigo acessar indice por indice pra deixar formatado sabe? =/
Eu to indo pelo CI primeiro pq dei uma lida e falaram que era o com menor curva de aprendizado euaheu

Comment: e[key].nomeDoCampo

Eu não conheço CI mas Laravel tá muito show, crescendo e dominando o mercado. Mas atenção que nada contra CI. :)

Comment: Pretendo migrar p/ laravel quando me sentir confiante com o CI, notei esse crescimento tb. Quanto a solução, desse jeito me retorna undefined =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolvido!**

Caso ajude alguem futuramente, o que estava dando erro é que eu não estava informando o datatype na requisição ajax, e por causa disso não estava conseguindo acessar os indices retornados em json!

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a sua resposta depois, ok?

Comment: Olá, sou novo aqui e ainda estou meio perdido, como assim marcar a resposta?

Comment: "Aceite" sua própria resposta como correta.